# templatefunctions.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

ok, I have the functions defined in the "template-functions.php" file, then what I am trying to do is to call the functions depending on the post_type  in the archive.php file like so:

```
get_header();
?>

<?php 
    if ($post_type == 'A') { ?>
        <div><?php function_1(); ?></div>
  } 
    <?php elseif
     ($post_type == 'B') { ?>
        <div><?php function_2(); ?></div>
  } 
    <?php elseif
     ($post_type == 'C') { ?>
        <div><?php function_3(); ?></div>
  } 
    <?php else
     ($post_type == 'D') { ?>
        <div><?php function_4(); ?></div>
  } 
?>
```

but seems I am missing something. Could anyone throw me a bone?
Thanks and cheers

Comment: it is actually difficult to help if you don't explain what is wrong. What "are you missing" exactly? what should those functions do? Add some more details please

Comment: Where is `$post_type` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the problem was I was opening and closing the php tags in the wrong way:

```
get_header();
?>

<?php
if ( $post->post_type == "A" ) : ?>
  <div><?php function_1(); ?></div>
<?php
elseif ( $post->post_type == "B" ) : ?>
  <div><?php function_2(); ?></div>
<?php
elseif ( $post->post_type == "C" ) : ?>
  <div><?php function_3(); ?></div>
<?php
elseif ( $post->post_type == "D" ) : ?>
  <div><?php function_4(); ?></div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```